# window.location + custom window.location.search

Tags: javascript, get, onclick, reload, window.location

This function basically reloads the page adding `?var=foo` to the URL so the reloaded page looks like.  `http://midomain.com/mypage.php?var=foo`

```
pub.reload = function() {
    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + "?var=foo";;
};
```

It works when I call the function from the JS console..

But surprisingly it does not work when I call it from a button in the HTML. 
`<button onclick="pub.reload()">`
Calling it this way the page reloads but the extra string is not added to the URL. (tested on CH and FF)
I am pulling my hairs trying to figure out why such a simple functions acts in two different ways depending on who calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? It seems to work fine to me.

```
<script>

var pub = {};

pub.reload = function() {
    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + "?var=foo";
};

</script>

<button onclick="pub.reload()">Click me</button>
```

:) you probably forgot to make the variable "pub" an object, because if you only did `var pub;` you would get an error defining .reload:
mypage.php?var=foo:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'reload' of undefined

Comment: pub is there because the function is wrapped this way

(function(pub, $, undefined) {
...
})(pub = window.pub || {}, jQuery);

Comment: oh sorry, I am not really familiar with JQuery, but im confident that pub isn't an object then, hope this helps you to figure it out